# Equilibrium solution using polar coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the equilibrium temperature on a half-disk of radius 1 when the temperature is held to 1 degree on the curved edge, while the straight edge is insulated.

For this problem I think the solution uses Laplace equation in polar coordinates using method of separation of variables. However, I'm not sure how to derive the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u(r,\theta)$ be the solution in polar coordinates, $0<r\le1$, $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$.

- The temperature is held to 1º on the curved edge: $u(1,\theta)=1$, $0\le\theta\le\pi/2$.
- The straight edge is insulated. This is a little more complicated. In cartesian coordinates it would be $u_y(x,0)=0$. Since $u_y=u_r\sin\theta+u_\theta\cos\theta$, this translates into $u_\theta(r,0)=u_\theta(r,\pi)=0$, $0<r\le1$.

Comment: Could you explain why the insulated condition means $u_y(x,0) = 0$?

Comment: $u_y(x,0)$ represents the heat flux through the line $y=0$ (Newton's law: heat flux is proportional to the gradient of the temperature). Insulation means that there is no heat flux through that line, so $u_y=0$.

Comment: Thank you. Would $0 \leq \theta \leq \bf{\pi}$ since the domain is a half disk?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I'm a little confused about your $u_y$. I get $u_y = u_r / \sin \theta + u_\theta / (r\cos\theta)$.

Comment: $r_y=y/r=\sin\theta$ and $r_x=x/r=\cos\theta$.

Comment: Would I need $\theta_y$ instead of $r_x$ for the second term?

Comment: I am sorry, it was a typo. $\theta_y=x/r=\sin\theta$.